# Breadcrumb/block settings

Tags: views, blocks, 7, breadcrumbs

Should Views (that are setup as a Page) be able to inherit breadcrumbs/block visibility settings? When I create a Views page, set a path, add it to the menu (then adjust it to be a sub-menu of another parent item), when I am on the actual Views page, it looses (in this case) any block settings that should be shown on this page. From the screen shot below, you can see the menu block disappear (as well as the LEAD logo on the lower left side). More odd than that, is whenever I set the View to be added to a menu (as I have done in the Views settings), it doesn't show up (which is why I had to add it to the menu manually). I've gotten it to work with another Views page (the menu link showing up), but the blocks still disappear.

Also, once you click on an individual node, they also loose any type of breadcrumb/block visibility (even though I've set the URL to be the correct breadcrumb /about/faculty-staff/directory/USER_ID). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Current setup:
Drupal 7.5
Views: 3.0-rc1
Menu Block: 2.2

[image: screenshot]

**Screenshot Explanation:**

Directory page (Views page - blocks missing from this page)

Main Faculty & Staff page (parent page)

User Profile view

Views config

Menu list

Menu config

Comment: The first thing to do is update to Drupal v7.9, your Views and Menu block look current. also, please clarify that you do not have any articles, pages etc. with the same URL. You can edit your question to reflect any changes in conditions this brings.

Comment: Hi @Joes,
Was fearing that'd be the answer ;) Views hasnt' come out with another RC in quite some time and hate to be mixed in with the madness of a development version - I'm assuming this wouldn't be a core Drupal issue... but maybe its' a combo of all of these freaking out. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us know if upgrading fixes the problem.  Note that interim upgrades usually fix bugs and do not add features.  Each new upgrade is an improvement not a renewed risk.  Moving on to a new Major version such as from 7 to 8 includes new features and more caution is advised.

Comment: Hi @Joes I upgraded Drupal to 7.9 as well as Views to the latest dev - but the issue is still there. I did some searching... http://drupal.org/node/1069502 could this be a core issue? Does my original question make sense? Nodes that are called from a Views listing should keep the block visibility settings of the View itself as long as their path is specified to match the Views page? Thanks.

Comment: That link does look like the same breadcrumb problem.  As for the blocks disappearing, you may have two issues here. What theme are you using?  Have you tried another to see if anything changes (try seven theme - its very basic). I agree that the view settings should work, blocks are dumb, I don't think they change anything. The block is apparently not being called (why? :}).  You may need to start backtracking the call for the blocks through the templates (something I am only beginning to research).  I'm very interested in where this issue goes.

Answer (score 0):

To your first problem, the menu disappearing on about/faculty-staff/directory:

- Check how the menu block is configured.
- Check if there is another menu item in another menu that links to this page. It could be that Drupal picks this up and thinks we are in another menu.

(There is a more general solution that I am going to post in another answer)

Answer (score 0):

A generally useful way to fix all of this:

- Use [Crumbs](http://drupal.org/project/crumbs) to generate the breadcrumbs.
- Use [Menupoly](http://drupal.org/project/menupoly) instead of Menu block, to have your submenus expand for items that are in the breadcrumb trail, even if the current page itself is not in any menu.

Configure **Crumbs** (7.x-2.*):

- Visit the configuration at Admin > Structure > Crumbs > Plugin weights,
  Make sure the menu plugin for this specific menu is enabled (or some parent plugin wildcard key). If necessary, give this specific menu a higher priority than other menus.
- Go to Admin > Structure > Crumbs > Entity parent > User,
  Set about/faculty-staff/directory as the parent path for users with "staff" role.
- Alternative: Use the "Path alias" plugin, where the parent path is based on the url alias.

Note.
You could also use [Easy Breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb) or [Breadcrumbs by path](https://drupal.org/project/breadcrumbs_by_path) to get breadcrumbs based on url alias. This would be equivalent with only having the "url alias" plugin enabled in Crumbs. But it does not do anything else, and it does not support Menupoly.

Define the menu with **Menupoly**:

- Create a custom module
- Implement hook_menupoly(). See the [example module](http://drupalcode.org/project/menupoly.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/example/menupoly_example.module) for inspiration.
- Go to Admin > Structure > Blocks, and move the newly created menupoly block to the sidebar.

E.g.:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menupoly()
 */
function MYMODULE_menupoly() {
  return array(
    'sidebar_menu' => array(
      'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
      'expand' => MENUPOLY_EXPAND_ACTIVE,
    ),
  );
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind disappearing of `block` is still not able to find `region` in pages just like `page.tpl.php`.

**Suggestions:**

1) Create a custom template for `views` page using `theme_preprocess_page` in `template.php`.You have to create `template` using `theme_hook_suggestions` under the condition of `views` page `url`.

2)Assign or create `region` in new `views` page template.

3)Assign your `menu block` in above `region`.

**Note:** You don't need to edit or create any `views` template like `views.tpl.php`.It should be custom just like `page.tpl.php`.

Also `block` visibility settings should be available to `views` page `url`